# a [box [of apples] ] vs [a box] [of apples]

Tags: syntactic-analysis, determiners, noun-phrases, constituents

The standard linguistic analysis of the NP

*a box of apples*

is that we have a determiner (*a*) which acts on (modifies?) *box of apples*. (For an example of standard analysis, see e.g. Fig. 6 [here](http://www.public.asu.edu/~gelderen/314text/chap3.htm)). [CGEL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) refers to *box of apples* as a *nominal*, though I understand that others would prefer to call it an NP'. Then *box of apples* is further parsed into *box* being modified by *of apples*. In other words, we have

[image]

My question is: what is the evidence against the following alternative parsing: *a box* being modified by *of apples*?

[image]

In other words, why does

*a* [*box* [*of apples*] ]

make more sense than

[*a box*] [*of apples*]?

Equivalently: why is *a* taken to modify *box of apples* rather than *of apples* taken to modify *a box*?

What is particularly impressive (or surprising) is that, on the standard analysis, the parsing seems to be completely independent of context. It is simply **never** the case that *a box* gets modified by *of apples*; it is **always** *box* being modified by *of apples*, and then *a* modifying *box of apples*.

I hope it is understood that I'm only mentioning *a box of apples* for the sake of concreteness. What I would like to know is why such a parsing applies in all relevantly similar cases. In other words, my actual question is: consider an NP which is Det + Head + PP. Why is Det taken to modify Head + PP, rather than PP taken to modify Det + Head?

I'm sure there is more than one piece of evidence, and would appreciate it if someone could explain the first several *strongest* pieces of evidence.

(In contrast, I find the standard parsing far more intuitive in the cases of NPs which look like Det + Mod + Head, e.g. *an old man*. The correct parsing is, of course, *an* [*old man*], and somehow I don't have the slightest inclination to parse it as [*an old*] *man*.)

**Update 1:** found a page that seems to say something relevant on the issue: [this one](http://allthingslinguistic.com/post/100781064586/how-to-draw-syntax-trees-part-4-type-2-a). Still digesting it...

**Update 2:** I have accepted the answer given by Greg Lee. (Thanks!) The answer uses the notion of a *pro-form*. A pro-form is a particular type of *function word*---"a word that has little lexical meaning or has ambiguous meaning, but instead serves to express grammatical relationships with other words within a sentence, or specify the attitude or mood of the speaker" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_word)). For completeness, here are details (also from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-form)):

> A *pro-form* is a type of function word or expression that stands in
>   for (expresses the same content as) another word, phrase, clause or
>   sentence where the meaning is recoverable from the context. They are
>   used either to avoid repetitive expressions or in quantification
>   (limiting the variables of a proposition).
>
> Pro-forms are divided into several categories, according to which part
>   of speech they substitute:
>
> - A *pronoun* substitutes a noun or a noun phrase, with or without a    determiner: it, this. (Compare also
>     [prop-word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prop-word); this denotes a
>     word like *one* in "the blue *one*".)
> - A *pro-adjective* substitutes an adjective or a phrase that functions as an adjective: *so* as in "It is less *so* than we had
>     expected."
> - A *pro-adverb* substitutes an adverb or a phrase that functions as an adverb: *how* or *this way*.
> - A *pro-verb* substitutes a verb or a verb phrase: *do*.
> - A *pro-sentence* substitutes an entire sentence or subsentence: *Yes*, or *that* as in "*That* is true".

Now the answer by Greg Lee is easy to follow (some of the emphases are mine):

> One generally assumes that only *constituents* can be replaced by a
>   pro-form and that only a constituent can be the antecedent for such a
>   replacement.  So since we can go from
>
> *I want a big box of apples, but my sister wants only a small box of apples.*
>
> to
>
> *I want a big box of apples, but my sister wants only a small one.*
>
> then "box of apples" must be a constituent.  This rules out the
>   structure: [*a* (Adj) *box*] [*of apples*].  It must be instead: *a*
>   (Adj) [*box of apples*].

Once this answer was posted, it was easy to find other resources that discuss this; one of them is [here](http://public.wsu.edu/~gordonl/S04/256/Constituents.htm).

Comment: You might find [this article by susan53 at ESLHQ Forums](http://www.eslhq.com/forums/esl-forums/english-questions/partitives-quantifiers-what-difference-6989/) interesting and even helpful.

Comment: Aleluya, an interesting grammar question. Thank you!

Comment: Consider: "I don't want ***a*** box of apples, I want ***that*** box of apples." Of course, in other contexts the alternative parsing might make more sense. I can't think of any such contexts offhand, but I'll leave it as a challenge.

Comment: @peter-shor Well, we are told that the head in any case is _box_, and that the rest are mere modifiers. But if that is so, then what's wrong with the following way of understanding your example: "I don't want **a** box, I want **that** box (and by the way, all and any of them are filled with apples)"? And if that's OK, then why _wouldn't_ we parse the NPs as [_a box_] [_of apples_] and [_that box_] [_of apples_]?

Comment: @linguisticturn You ask: "what is the evidence against the following alternative parsing: a box being **modified** by of apples"? But then you diagram your alternative with the PP "of apples" labelled 'complement'! (Complement and modifier are quite different functions). Ignoring that apparent contradiction, you've actually answered the question yourself. The difference is that CGEL recognise a unit intermediate between the NP and the noun which they call a "nominal" Thus the higher NP, not the nominal, includes the determiner. I thought CGEL explained the rationale for that quite clearly.

Comment: @linguisticturn You also ask: "why is _a_ taken to modify _box of apples_ rather than _of apples_ taken to modify _a box_? Well, it doesn't. The article "a" is a determiner, and determiners are not modifiers: they don't modify anything; they simply mark the NP as definite or indefinite.

Comment: @billj 1. Sorry for being careless (in truth, a bit ignorant) about the terminology ("complement"; "modifier"). But I hope the spirit of the question is clear.2.Could you tell me where in CGEL is that argued for, as opposed to merely asserted? I did look, but all I found was an argument for why in _a number of protesters_ the _of_ belongs with _protesters_ and not with _a number_ (p. 351). Of course, it's a thick book...  3. Please note **Update 2**. By the way, since the word "pro-form" doesn't appear in the chapter on NPs at all, it seems that Greg Lee's explanation is not presented in CGEL.

Comment: @linguisticturn Do you mean CGEL's argument for the intermediate level in an NP referred to as 'nominal'? I think this is discussed in Ch 5, pp329-330

Comment: @billj I guess so... depending on what that argument proves, and what it assumes. Of course, CGEL does _describe_ the category of a nominal in detail and in many examples. But my _impression_ was that they were implying that an actual argument for why-this-way-and-not-some-other-way was out of scope. I thought they were content to just describe their conclusions, which itself took them pages and pages.What I was _hoping_ for is an argument at the level of what Greg Lee presented.

Comment: @linguisticturn That might be too much for these confines!  Nevertheless, I have some notes on this somewhere. I'll see if I can find them.

Comment: @billj Wow, that would be great! By the way, you don't like Greg Lee's argument? Or the discussion [here](http://public.wsu.edu/~gordonl/S04/256/Constituents.htm)?

Comment: By the way, let me put in another plug for the textbook by James McCawley, **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**.  Comparing it with other instructional books, it gives reasons, rather just explaining a doctrine to be taken on authority.  The index is useful.  The exercises sometimes require you to do actual syntactic investigation.  The footnotes are almost always worth careful reading.  McCawley was a giant.

Comment: @greg-lee Thanks! I'll check it out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One generally assumes that only constituents can be replaced by an indefinite pro-form and that only a constituent can be the antecedent for such a replacement.  So since we can go from

> I want a big box of apples, but my sister wants only a small box of apples.

to

> I want a big box of apples, but my sister wants only a small one.

then "box of apples" must be a constituent.  This rules out the structure: [a (Adj) box] [of apples].  It must be instead: a (Adj) [box of apples].

Comment: It's obviously a [box full of apples] not a [box made out of apples]. If we are speaking of examples like: "fence of wood" or "house of stones". I guess you can make a box of apples if you try really hard.

Comment: @SovereignSun, Yes, and the passive "A box is made of apples" shows that in that sense, "box of apples" is not a constituent.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to say, but given the sentence

> We have a box of apples.

It's quite obvious what we mean. We literally have a box filled with apples. If we examine the phrase "...a box of apples" in the sentence, the phrase's 'subject' is the box. We use *a* becuase we have one of the many boxes in the world. We don't have just one grand box (*the* box) and we don't have every box (*every* box).

Further, the detail about the apples isn't necessary. The apples are not the 'subject', so they are a detail. Details by nature modify an overarching something that can contain one or many details. The sentence is just as correct if you remove "of apples".

> We have a box.

*Of* is a modifier similar to *a*. By that fact alone, the phrase "of apples" cannot stand independently and requires additional information.

Technically you can argue that a noun requires some kind of modifier to be used in a complete sentence. Proper English says

> Want buy box?

is incorrect. Even though the intent is obvious and technically a full coherent thought, it's not proper. The correct form is:

> Want *to* buy *a* box (*of* apples)?

Which can be further corrected to

> *Do* you want *to* buy *a* box (*of* apples)?

English itself was also built this way. Take something like gender expression. In other languages this can modify a word (El Niño vs El Niña). According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender),

> Modern English is not considered to have grammatical gender, although
> Old English had it, and some remnants of a gender system exist, such
> as the distinct personal pronouns *he*, *she*, and *it*. However, aside from
> a handful of nouns like "god" and "goddess", "duke" and "duchess",
> "tiger" and "tigress", and "waiter" and "waitress", grammatical gender
> is almost exclusively found in pronouns and titles. Since they
> accurately reflect the biological sex of whatever they represent, with
> all male animate beings being assigned as masculine, all female
> animate beings being assigned as feminine, and all inanimate objects
> being assigned as neuter, English is said to have natural gender.

We don't generally modify words themselves depending on usage. We have other words do that job for us.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47730/discussion-on-answer-by-superpentil-a-box-of-apples-vs-a-box-of-apples).