# Constituent structure of 'He arranged for me to go there'

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, constituents

This question was inspired by the discussions in [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/481918/are-these-pps-or-non-finite-clauses-or-something-else-entirely).

Consider the sentence

[1] *He arranged for me to go there.*

What is required is to determine its [constituent structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)) (in the sense of phrase structure grammars). Also required is a demonstration that the proposed structure is correct.

This much I will take to be uncontroversial: *He [arranged for me to go there]*. In other words, the words in the brackets are a constituent, namely a VP.

**The controversy**

But beyond that, there was a bit of a controversy. Some have argued (in effect) that *arranged for* is a constituent. I and others have argued that *for me to go there* is a constituent.

Note that these two claims are inconsistent; we can't have overlapping constituents. What can happen is that the structure of the clause is ambiguous, though usually that is accompanied by a difference in meaning. I do not think that *arranged for* is a constituent of [1] (at least not in the most obvious interpretation of the meaning of [1]), but if you think you have an argument that it is, this will be of interest.

**My original argument that *for me to go there* is a constituent**

I originally gave two arguments that *for me to go there* is a constituent.

Here is the first one (note that it will be called into question below!) Consider

[2] *He wished for me to go there and arranged it, too.*

The antecedent of *it* is *for me to go there*. But then, by the proform substitution (or, replacement) test, *for me to go there* is a constituent. (For more on this test, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_(linguistics)#Proform_substitution_(replacement)), [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/307884/155553), [here](http://languagelinguistics.com/2014/10/10/constituency-tests-in-syntax-linguistics/), …)

The second argument uses coordination. Consider

[3] *He arranged a nice dinner and for me to go there.*

*Usually* only constituents can be coordinated. Yes, there are some known exceptions that involve non-basic coordination, but if you rule those out, an argument from coordination can be successful. [CGEL's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) Sec. 15.4.6 ('Coordination as evidence for constituent structure') is precisely about that, and they dedicate two whole pages to working out an example in detail (pp. 1348-1350). I will not reproduce the whole thing here, but one needs to show that [3] cannot be analyzed as any of the following: 1. a clause-coordination with ellipsis of the subject and the verb, 2. a right nonce-constituent coordination, 3. a delayed right constituent coordination ([right-node raising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_node_raising), RNR). I believe I can do all that, but won't write it out right now.

**Problem 1: could *me to go there* be a constituent?**

There is a possible problem with the above analysis: a test analogous to that in [2] seems to suggest that *me to go there* is also a constituent:

[4] *He wished for me to go there and arranged for it, too.*

Now it seems that the antecedent of *it* is *me to go there*, and so, by the proform substitution test, *me to go there* is a constituent. The argument is exactly parallel to the one I gave for the constituenthood of *for me to go there*.

The problem with that is that to me (and some others, including Greg Lee) this seems very implausible and counterintuitive; it just doesn't *look* like a constituent. That's all—but it's enough.

And if *me to go there* is not, in fact, a constituent, then our reasons for thinking that *for me to go there* is one becomes less certain, because we used parallel arguments to establish their constituenthood.

Let me point out that I *could* in principle, live with *me to go there* being a constituent. It wouldn't contradict anything else I've been claiming. In particular, it wouldn't contradict that *for me to go there* is also a constituent; all it would say is that the constituent structure of *for me to go there* looks like this: *[for [me to go there] ]*.

<sup>Presumably it can be further shown that *to go there* is a constituent, and then CGEL (pp. 1185) has a general argument that this has the structure *[to [go there] ]*.</sup>

**Problem 2:**

In the comments to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/481920/155553), Greg Lee has challenged the analysis of [4] in the following way:

> By the same reasoning, is *I ... go there* a constituent in
>
> [5] *I seemed to go there because he wished for it* ?
>
> (Answer: no, because underlying constituents can be broken up by transformations, like Raising.)

Later on, he said that the problem with [4] is this:

> being an antecedent for definite anaphora doesn't show that a string of words is a constituent.

He also said that when anaphora is *indefinite*, then the substitution test is normally reliable.

Note that if this is a good objection to the test in [4], it is also a good objection to the test in [2].

<sup>(It turns out there is here is quite a bit of work that questions the assumptions behind the substitution tests, e.g. [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/english-language-and-linguistics/article/english-proforms-an-alternative-account/DC7D592FC8EEEE474740B07BAEF10412) and in the references in footnotes 10 and 11 [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Constituent_(linguistics)&oldid=861805893). However, none of those references seem to be addressing Greg Lee's point.)</sup>

**Additional tests**

So here are some additional tests one can do to establish that *for me to go there* is a constituent (while hoping that they will not also establish that *me to go there* is a constituent, too).

**Coordination, part 2**

But first, what does coordination say about *me to go there*? Consider tchrist's example:

[6] *<sup>???</sup>He arranged for an early dinner and me to go there.*

I have to say that I (and some other people) do not find this acceptable at all (though it seems at least some people do). If this is not acceptable, that doesn't in and of itself yet mean that *me to go there* can't be a constituent, but it's promising that this test doesn't offer any evidence that it *is* a constituent.

Now let's look at other tests.

**Fronting**: *<sup>?</sup>[For me to go there], he arranged.* This is a bit Yoda-esque, but definitely much better than  **[Me to go there], he arranged for*. So this test provides marginal evidence that *for me to go there* is a constituent, and no evidence that *me to go there* is.

**Heavy-NP-Shift**: in our case, this will be a misnomer because what we'll be shifting is not an NP, but rather something that can appear in many functions in which an NP can appear. Consider these sentences: *He arranged for me to go there himself; He arranged himself for me to go there*. Since we were able to move *for me to go there*, it is a constituent. In contrast, **He arranged for himself me to go there* doesn't work at all. So this is good evidence that *for me to go there* is a constituent, and no evidence that *me to go there* is. Note that the move becomes more and more preferable the 'heavier' (i.e. longer) the phrase: *He arranged for me to very quickly and without delay go there himself* is awkward, while this is much better: *He arranged himself for me to very quickly and without delay go there.*

**Clefting**: *<sup>?</sup>It was [for me to go there] that he arranged.* Again, not super-natural, but this doesn't work at all: **It was [me to go there] that he arranged for*. Overall verdict is like with fronting.

**Pseudo-clefting**: *<sup>?</sup>[For me to go there] is what he arranged.* Not great, but better than *<sup>?</sup>[Me to go there] is what he arranged for,* which, in turn, is a bit better than the constructions we've had so far in which *me to go there* was supposed to work as a constituent. So, weak evidence that *for me to go there* is a constituent, and marginal evidence that *me to go there* is.

**Answer fragment**: Q: *What did he arrange?* A: *For me to go there.* I think this is the most natural so far in this section, thus good evidence that *for me to go there* is a constituent. Now what about  Q: *<sup>?</sup>What did he arrange for?* A: *Me to go there*. Personally, I would probably hesitate before saying that. But perhaps I would say it in the end, and I don't know if I would really pay much attention if someone else said it. So, marginal evidence that *me to go there* is a constituent.

**Passivization** *[For me to go there] was arranged by him* seems fine. The prepositional passive doesn't work: **Me to go there was arranged for by him.* So good evidence that *for me to go there* is a constituent, and no evidence that *me to go there* is.

<sup>Note that this is fine: *My going there was arranged for by him.* The non-passivized version is fine, too: *He arranged for my going there*. In this case, *for* is a preposition taking a non-finite, gerund-participial clause as complement, which prepositions readily do, e.g. *They're talking [about **my moving to New York**].* In contrast, in [1] and all the other clauses we've been looking at so far, *for* is not a preposition—at least according to CGEL (see [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/482032/155553)) and [some other sources](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/482128/155553).)</sup>

**Parenthetical Insertion**: *He arranged, hopefully, for me to go there* is fine. *<sup>?</sup>He arranged for, hopefully, me to go there* is much less so.

Overall, it seems to me that we have a pretty strong case that *for me to go there* is a constituent of [1]. The case that *me to go there* is a constituent is much weaker, but it's not nonexistent.

**Questions**

1. Is there some better way to show that *for me to go there* is a constituent (if it is one)? (Better than any of those I presented above.)
2. Is there an argument that *arrange for* **isn't** a constituent? (Is there one that it is?)
3. Is *me to go there* a constituent? If not, can a reason be given? (Note that failing a constituency test is in general *not* evidence that something isn't a constituent. Failing any one such test—or even failing all of them—merely says that  the question remains open.)
4. Can someone clarify the problem with the substitution test (definite vs indefinite anaphora)? I googled for it quite a bit, but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to make the substitution test work to show that *for me to go there* is a constituent (preferably in such a way that there isn't a parallel argument that would show that *me to go there* is a constituent)?

Comment: Using "arrange" for your test case maximizes the confusion level, since this particular verb takes either a PP or a NP complement: "He arranged a party.", "He arranged for a party." And so since prepositions are normally lost  before sentence complements, "He arranged for us to celebrate.", we have to wonder whether the "for" is a preposition or a complementizer.  (It's the latter.)

Comment: Concerning the anaphora test for constituent-hood, I should refer you to McCawley's text, which has an excellent discussion of the two fundamentally different kinds of anaphora.  What I call here "definite" anaphora, I believe McCawley calls "essential" anaphora.  Earlier, Lakoff referred to the distinction between "identity of reference" and "identity of sense" anaphora, appealing to Frege's difference between sense and reference.

Comment: Continuing my comment above on anaphora, you can read McCawley's discussion online here: https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&q=essential#v=snippet&q=essential&f=false  Go to the 3rd reference to the word "essential" on p. 343 in chapter 11. What I have called "indefinite anaphora", M. calls "derived anaphora".

Answer (score 2):

```
  [S he [VP arranged [PP (for) [NP for me to go there]] ] ]
```

where "(for)" means this preposition is not expressed, but is understood.  If the complement "I go there" is nominalized using the complementizer "that" instead of for-to,
the preposition is still deleted:

```
  [S he [VP arranged [PP (for) [NP that I would go there]] ] ]
```

If the sentence complement is pronominalized by an appropriate antecedent, however, the preposition is not lost:

```
  [S he [VP arranged [PP for [NP it]] ] ]
```

This is a systematic phenomenon that prepositions are lost before sentence complements. Compare for instance "We decided that we should leave/on leaving/to leave".

Apparently, "arrange" can also take a NP direct object complement.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have many questions. The main one is this: what is your favorite **argument** that *for me to go there* in your first sentence is a constituent? Suppose I claimed that the structure is instead *[for] [me] [to go there]*, where I claim that these three do not form a single constituent. What is your favorite, cleanest, least theory-laden way to prove me wrong?

Comment: Passive *For me to go there was arranged.*  Pseudo-cleft *For me to go there is what he arranged (?for),*

Comment: Great, thanks! Next question: what is the argument that there is an unexpressed preposition in your first two sentences? This claim I take to be equivalent to the claim that *arrange* only takes PPs as complements. Why couldn't *arrange* take NPs and content clauses as complements as well?

Comment: I've given the argument.  When an abstract noun replaces the nominalized S, the preposition occurs explicitly, and prepositions are always lost before a for-to complement.  I said that *arrange* also takes an NP complement. *He aranged for a party. He arranged a party.*

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit slow. I'm probably missing something concerning 'abstract noun replacing the nominalized S'. Let me put it this way. The following would make sense to me: if a verb **doesn't** take an NP complement but only a PP of the form *for* + NP, then: if that NP is a *for to*- phrase, then the preposition *for* is omitted (presumably to avoid a repeated *for*).

Comment: What I don't understand is this: suppose the verb can **alternatively** take an NP complement. Well, you say that the *for to* phrase is an NP. Why claim that this *for to* phrase is a complement of the unexpressed preposition *for*, as opposed to an immediate complement of the verb? I guess the answer has to do with this part I probably don't get ('abstract noun...'), but... unfortunately, I don't see it.

Comment: (MCCawley discusses nominalization on pp. 406-420, and it seems that none of the examples there are *for to* phrases. Those are discussed on pp. 116-126 and are not referred to as nominalizations in his book, as best as I can tell. What are you referring to when you say *the nominalized S*? Is it *for me to go there*?)

Comment: Since both NP and PP are possible complements of *arrange* and since a for-to complement is a NP, without some ad hoc constraint to the contrary, the for-to complement after *arrange* could be either a direct object or object of the PP.  So that's my prediction.

Comment: It's my recollection that McCawley treats all 3 complements, for-to/that/POSS-ing, as nomminalizations (following Robert Lees' classic *Grammar of English Nominalization*).  I don't have McCawley's text at hand., but I'm sure that's right.

Comment: OK, I'll try to check McCawley more thoroughly when I get the chance. Meanwhile, just to make sure I understood you correctly: are you saying that it is also possible that there is **no** unexpressed preposition *for* in *He arranged for me to go there*? In other words, are you saying that the following is **also** a possible constituent structure of that sentence, in addition to the structure at the top of your answer:  *[S he [VP arranged [NP for me to go there] ] ]* ?

Comment: Yes. The last is the source for the passive *For me to go there was arranged by him.* I said earlier that choosing this particular verb maximized the confusion level because it takes a preposition that happens to be the same as the initial part of the for-to complementizer.

Comment: Thanks! One final question for now: why do you say that *for me to go there* is an NP? I know it can perform many of the same functions a 'standard' NP (det+noun) can, and in particular it can be the subject of a clause: *[For me to go there] is unthinkable*. But so can *to go there*: *[to go there] is unthinkable*. Should we say that *to go there* is therefore also an NP? That seems wrong in light of such examples as *he proceeded [to go there]*; no 'standard' NP can appear there instead of *to go there* (neither can a *for to* phrase).

Comment: But there are also verbs that take either a *to* or a *for to* phrase as complement, but not any 'standard' NP: *He longed [(for her) to come home]*. On the other hand, there do not seem to be any verbs that take just *for to* but not *to* phrases. In light of all that, doesn't it seem more reasonable to say that *to go there* and *for me to go there* are both non-finite, *to*-infinitival clauses, except that the latter one has an overt subject?

Comment: I'm looking over the examples you mention, which you seem to think are problematic, but I don't see the problems.  Yes, sometimes a for-to complement appears without the for-NP part when the subject of the underlying clause is not specified or is predictable because of an antecedent.  So?  Why does this lead you to doubt the analysis?  The details are complicated -- why should they be simple?  Because I analyze some for-to expressions as NPs, did I somehow predict that every such expression is a NP?  No, I didn't.  It's okay for things to be complicated.

Comment: OK. In *He arranged [to go there]*, is *to go there* also an NP? (If not, why analyze it differently than *for me to go there*?)

Comment: I think it is also a NP.  I recall that Rosenbaum maintained that some similar complements are not NPs -- I don't recall the details.  Why do you ask?  Here we have, for instance, *He arranged to go there and bragged about arranging (for) it.*

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the argument is this: in *He arranged to go there and bragged about arranging (for) it*, the antecedent of *it* is *to go there*, and so the latter must be an NP. Now consider this: *I went there because he wished for it*. It seems that now the antecedent of *it* is *I went there*. Is *I went there* therefore an NP as well? (I would think that what these examples show is not that *to go there* and *I went there* are NPs, but rather that the antecedent of *it* need not be an NP.)

Comment: Yes, independent clauses can also be antecedents for *it*, and also for *which*.  I don't understand this.  (Note antecedent for *this* in preceding S.)

Comment: My question was what is the argument that *to go there* is an NP in *He arranged [to go there]*. I thought your example with *bragged about arranging (for) it* was that argument, namely that *to go there* is an antecedent of *it*. But if we know that things other than NPs can be antecedents of *it*, it would seem that the argument that *to go there* is an NP then loses force. And if so, an alternative analysis looks stronger: one according to which *to go there* is (in all cases) a 'non-finite clause'—not an NP but a construction with a distinctive distribution and internal structure.

Comment: Of course *to go there* is "a construction with a distrinctive distribution and internal structure".  That isn't controversial, nor informative.  How is that "an alternative analysis"?  It's puzzling that independent sentences and nominalized sentences can both be antecedents for *it*, but I don't see a solution to that puzzle in what you're saying.  Do you?

Comment: I re-read your comment.  I didn't argue that "to go there" is a NP because it can an antecedent for "it",  That's a misunderstanding.  The significance of "He arranged for it" with the interpretation "(for him) to go there" is that "it", a NP, has replaced "(for him) to go there".  It has nothing to do with what the antecedent is like.

Comment: I see, I was careless: A replacing B is not the same as B being an antecedent for A. But the argument will go just the same, though? I'll say next that in *I went there because he wished for it* we have *it* replacing *I went there*, and so *it* can replace independent sentences as well as nominalized sentences. And you will say that, OK, that's puzzling, but the puzzle isn't made any clearer by denying that *to go there* is an NP. Is that much correct?

Comment: In your example, *it* replaces the object of *for*, which is not an independent sentence,